# Dhtmlx widgets with emberjs library

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx, ember.js

I have been reading about emberjs in order to use dhtmlx components (http://dhtmlx.com/) with emberjs. What should I do to be able to use dhtmlx grid or combobox components along with emberjs?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

there is a updated version of the article ghempton have posted : http://www.lukemelia.com/devblog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/

Perhaps you can apply the same technique.

Good luck, currently I am trying to mix jq mobile and emberjs... But I have some issues ;-)

Comment: why do you want jqm with ember js? Dont take this offensive, i am looking for any reasons to keep jqm with ember despite of the fact that its consuming many resources.

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with dhtmlx, but if its anything like jQuery UI, the following link will help: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/06/11/using-sproutcore-2-0-with-jquery-ui/